# Is there any downside to marking all C++ constructors explicit?

Tags: c++, performance, explicit-constructor

A few times, when refactoring code, I have forgotten to add the `explicit` keyword when adding a parameter to a previously-parameterless constructor, or removing parameters from a previously multi-parameter constructor. To prevent this, I have gotten in the habit of marking every constructor `explicit`, no matter no many arguments it has. (Except, of course, those constructors for which I actually want implicit conversion.)

Is there any downside to this? Performance? Compile time?

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607047/why-constructors-arent-explicit-by-default

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't have any downsides. It will be future safe, because in C++0x multi-parameter constructors participate in initializations using multi-element initializer lists and can forbidden to be used in the cases where only implicit conversions apply using `explicit`.

So if you find out a give multi-parameter constructor does not logically represent the value of your class, I think it's good to make it `explicit` (example: I would set a container constructor `(size_t size, T defaultValue)` be `explicit`, while the constructor of `pair`, `(T first, U second)` be set non-explicit).

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure, but I think it does have some unexpected consequences for the copy constructor to be `explicit`.  Other than that, I think yo're OK.

Comment: good point with the copy constructor, I wonder the effect on pass/return by value.

Comment: It was explained to me once; my conclusion was just to not make copy constructors explicit, and not worry about the details.  IIRC, yes, it meant that objects of that type could not be passed to functions by value.  But I'm no longer sure.

Comment: This sounded familiar, and indeed: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/131511-explicit-copy-constructor. CWG 152, fixed in C++03.

Answer (score 4):

There will be no runtime performance difference. The compile time difference is likely to be undetectable.

I think there is no harm in declaring all constructors with arguments `explicit`, except that it might look redundant for those with more than one argument.

If you declare a type with an `explicit` default constructor, you may have trouble using it with collection types.